# Cannot uninstall third party softwares in mac

Tags: mac

I installed software which was downloaded from net

[image]

But when i tried to uninstall this app in mac, i searched in finder but nothing shows to uninstall.

But this app is in installation list

[image]

How to uninstall this software from MAC

Answer (score 3):

## Contact Mobile Stream

Contact the developers of [Easy Tether USB](http://www.mobile-stream.com/support.html), Mobile Stream. They are best placed to help you remove the software.

By contacting the developers, you will help prompt them to provide better uninstall support.

### Manually Removing Easy Tether's KEXT

If Mobile Stream are unable to help, you can manually [unload the kernel extension](https://superuser.com/questions/385/how-do-i-uninstall-and-remove-a-kext-on-mac-os-x) using the following command:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
```

Next, find and remove the following file. You will need administrator rights to delete this file:

```
/System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
```

This assumes you installed the [EasyTether - Android Tether Solution](http://easytether.blogspot.fr/2010/10/easytether-drivers.html) driver.

[image]

Comment: Manually removing files is not without risk, specialty when using the rm -rf, for NOT experienced user.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the answer to remove the use of `rm -rf`.